# How to listen to an Ubuntu computer's music library over WiFi on an iPhone

Tags: 18.04, wireless, music, iphone

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04, with a large collection of music, and would like to listen to it on an iPhone, preferable connected of WiFi.
I remember being able to do that with Clementine and an Android phone, and used to absolutely love that feature, however: (1) I now use an iPhone (because that was what was available as hand-me-downs) and (2) Clementine seems to not have had a release since 2016.

Any idea how I could set that up?

Comment: A Samba share on Ubuntu would allow the music to be visible to machines on the network. Not sure which iOS music application might support network shares and have all the features you're looking for, but there's likely something in the AppStore that fits the bill.

Comment: If you can run a DLNA server on your laptop, you should be able to install a DLNA client on your iPhone and listen to your music collection.